# Spring Thrown JpaSystemException instead of DuplicateKeyException

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, unique-constraint

I'm in troubles with DataAccessException handling.

When an uniquess key constraint is violated I got an JpaSystemException, and not a DuplicateKeyException!

I found some thread talking about this problem, but no one help me to solve the problem. How can I map to a concrete org.springframework.dao exception?

My persistence.xml file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>        
        <class>...</class>
        <class>...</class>
        ...
        <exclude-unlisted-classes />
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/> 
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show.sql" value="true"/>

            <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
    </properties>         
    </persistence-unit>    
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitI24" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>...</class>
        <class>...</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes />
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.showsql" value="true"/>           
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit> 
</persistence>
```

And the configurations about mysql transaction manager:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
          p:persistenceUnitName="persistenceUnit"
          p:jpaProperties="">
          <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
              <property name="showSql" value="true" />
              <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
              <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>           
         </bean>
       </property>
           <property name="jpaDialect">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
           </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

I've omitted the configuration about sqlserver because I think that is not relevant. I'm not interested in translation error about this db.

I've also included the bean:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

Trying to to do the following simple junit test:

```
@Test(expected=DuplicateKeyException.class)
public void createNewUbi(){
    Ubi ubi = new Ubi();
    ubi.setCode("A");
    ubiDao.save(ubi);       

    ubi = new Ubi();
    ubi.setCode("A");

    ubiDao.save(ubi);                   
}
```

I got from my log:

```
ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Duplicate entry 'A' for key 'code'
```

Catching the exception of the second save call I noticed that I have:

```
JpaSystemException: cause: javax.persistence.PersistenceException
PersistenceException: cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException
```

If I try to do an insertion from the webapp I got this Exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:311)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:15)
    it.cpmapave.pm.dao.jpa.GenericDaoJpa.save(GenericDaoJpa.java:29)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy56.save(Unknown Source)
    it.cpmapave.pm.service.amministrazione.SettoreServiceImpl.saveSettore(SettoreServiceImpl.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy57.saveSettore(Unknown Source)
    it.cpmapave.pm.controller.amministrazione.SettoreController.create(SettoreController.java:42)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.invoke(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:84)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:279)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I've enabled mysql query logging and I got the following query:

```
insert into ubi (code, version) values ('A', 0)
```

If I try to execute the query from mysql console I got: `ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'A' for key 'code'`

Searching in `sql-error-codes.xml` in package `org.springframework.jdbc.support` of `spring-jdbc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar` i found that for mysql db the error code 1062 is configured in this way:

```
<property name="duplicateKeyCodes">
    <value>1062</value>
</property>
```

So I think that there is some Exception translating problem due to a misconfigured properties.. but which?

I'm using Spring 3.0.6.RELEASE and Hibernate 3.6.9.FINAL

Thank you for any reply!
Marco

Comment: @skaffman Ok, it is a subclass of UncategorizedDataAccessException and then of DataAccessException. Do you know how can i map to a categorized exception, like DuplicateKeyException in my case? Thank you!

Comment: @skaffman I've updated my post with more information.

Comment: I've found that when maven compile the project I get this WARNING:

advice defined in org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect has not been applied

Could it be a cause? :)

Comment: the cause is not that. nothing has changed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem isn't related to Spring or to your database driver. I had to work through this myself a while back. I was surprised to find that the hibernate-entitymanager jar, which lets you use Hibernate as a JPA provider, has some poor exception translation in it. The `AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert()` method is responsible for converting `HibernateException`s into JPA `PersistenceException`s, but it doesn't handle any kind of "duplicate key" or "unique constraint" exceptions at all. Even the [latest code on Github](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-entitymanager/src/main/java/org/hibernate/jpa/spi/AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java#L1527) doesn't seem to have fixed it. If you take a look at it, the convert() method has a long chain of ifs, but none of them cover that particular kind of exception, so it falls through to the bottom and gets translated to a generic `PersistenceException`. It's rather annoying.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your `EntityManager` has a `vendorAdapter` set on it.  This will allow your jpa provider to provide advanced error codes.

Answer (score 1):

I had this set in my config.

```
transactionManager.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
```

I commented it away and suddenly my application started to give DuplicateKeyException

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring ORM JPA Extension:

Extension to Spring ORM JPA module to provide Standard Spring
SQL Exception Translation similar to Spring JDBC module.

Home Page of extension is:
https://github.com/ankurpathak/spring-orm-jpa-extension

Simple example to use the extension in your project is:

```
@Configuration
public class JpaConfig {

    private final  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public JpaConfig(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new ExtendedLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(jdbcTemplate.getExceptionTranslator());
        emf.setDataSource(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
        emf.setPackagesToScan("com.github.ankurpathak.hibernatedemo");
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(new ExtendedHibernateJpaVendorAdaptor(jdbcTemplate.getExceptionTranslator()));
        Properties jpaProperties =  new Properties();
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", String.valueOf(Boolean.TRUE));
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", String.valueOf(Boolean.TRUE));
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        emf.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        return emf;
    }
}
```